# Using Jquery implemented throught Sourcerer in Joomla to load data from a file to DIV

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I am new to joomla. I am using sourcerer to implement php and javascript on ARTICLES. is it possible to load data to a DIV using Jquery on articles.
Calling this function yield nothing

```
{source}
<?php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();

$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::root( true ).'/media/system/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js');

echo'<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function Myfunction()
{    
$.get( "/location/sample.txt", function( data ) {
alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});

} </script>';

?>
{/source}
```

seems the issue is with the triggering. It should be triggered by a drop down. Have simplified it to just alert. kindly assist.

```
`{source}
<?php
 $db =& JFactory::getDBO();

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript(JURI::root( true ).'/media/system/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js');

$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
     $(document).ready(function(){function Myfunction(){alert("here");}

});
  '); 

echo '<select id="select1" name="ctlselect" onchange="Myfunction()">';
echo '<option value="1"> Option1 </option> ';                             
echo '<option value="2"> Option2 </option> '; 

echo '<option value="3"> Option3 </option> ';                           
echo '</select>';
?>
{/source}`
```

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is being imported? Check the console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: @Lodder TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function  SyntaxError: missing } after function body

Comment: @Lodder The first error "SyntaxError: missing } after function body" is not related with my page. it is caused by the template I am using. however upon selecting a new item on the dropdown (triggering the function) this error shows up "ReferenceError: Myfunction is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

You're echoing some javascript but it needs to be added to the head. This is where Joomla's API comes in handy.

```
{source}
<?php
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();

  $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
  $doc->addScript(JUri::root( true ).'/media/system/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js');

  $doc->addScriptDeclaration('
     $(document).ready(function() {
       function Myfunction(){    
          $.get( "' . JUri::root() . 'path/to/location/sample.txt", function( data ) {
             alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
          });    
       }
     });
  ');   
?>
{/source}
```

As shown above, I would also recommend using `JUri::root()` to define the root of your site when calling the file. Also, seeing as you're using jQuery Ajax, you need to wrap your code in `document.ready`, also, as shown above. One more thing to note, you have wrapped your code within a function, so be sure to actually call the function, else the code won't run. If you simple want to code to run without any triggers (such as a click), then take the code outside the function.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I implemented it as you have stated but still no results `code` {source}
<?php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::root( true ).'/media/system/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js');
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
     $(document).ready(function() {
       function Myfunction(){   
          $.get( "' . JUri::root() . 'sample.txt", function( data ) {
             alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
          });   
       }
     });
  ');`code`

Comment: Like I said in my comments below the answer, are you calling the function? If not, take the jQuery Ajax code outside of the function else make a call to it

Comment: triger `code`echo '<select id="select1" name="selct" onchange="Myfunction()"> <option value="1"> Option1</option> <option value="2"> Option2</option>'; ?>
{/source} `code`. I have checked on the page source and as you stated the script has been added `code` <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() { 
       function Myfunction(){     
          $.get( "http://localhost/mysite/sample.txt", function( data ) { 
             alert( "Data Loaded: " + data ); 
          });     
       } 
     }); 
  </script> `code`

Comment: Can you please add you full code to your question. Also start using `console.log()` to help debug as it comes in very handy